# Why is my do-while loop gets infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm checking if inputs are empty and increment integer whenever I find one. I thought I set my do-while loop right, but it keeps getting into an infinite loop.

```
do
{
    var inVal = 0;
    $(".inErr").text("");
    $(".info").each(function() {
        var e = $(this);
        if (e.val() == "") {
            $("#"+e.attr("data-err")).text("*Field is empty");
            inVal++;
        }
    });
} while ( inVal != 0 );
```

I expect to escape do-while loop once all e.val()'s are filled.

[Edit]
Just found out I didn't need a do-while loop to begin with... sorry for the poor question and thank you all for helping me.

Comment: you're saying "loop as long as inVal isn't zero" -- but if you keep incrementing it from zero, by the time it hits the while, it will never reach zero. It starts at one, and only goes up from there.

Comment: Your loop is set to run as long as `inVal` is not 0. Once you reach `inVal++`, it's always greater than 0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to evaluate without the rest of the code. But i'd say you either never enter the internal `each` loop because the selector returns nothing or an empty array, or the `if` condition is never met.

I would suggest putting `console.logs` into both to evaluate where the issue is.

Comment: I added a console.log and i think i see the problem. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you decalre `inVal` var inside the do/while scope, so `inVal` will have `undefine` value when the while compare its value with `0`, anyway you're starting the counter with 0 and increasing it so it alway will be != 0, in fact, will be `> 0`

```
var inVal = 0;  // declare it outside the do/while scope
do
{
    ...
} while ( inVal != 0 );
```

Comment: There would be no difference between having `inVal` inside or outside the loop in this case. Well, aside from being reset all the time but that's not where the problem lies.

Comment: While is this case you are right and it's not the issue, I think he was still right to point it out as it will most likely be an issue is most cases.

Comment: @Morphyish but saying that `inVal` will be `undefined` when the condition is checked is absolutely wrong - this will *never* happen. And the suggestion that stems from that assumption is actively *misleading*. It's a good suggestion, yes, but not when it actively misinforms in how the language operates.

Comment: fair enough, the explanation that goes with it isn't great